# How to get rid of having *already merged* commits being ahead of origin branch

Tags: github, git-commit, git-fork

On my gihub forked repo, it is said that the master branch is 9 commits ahead of the parent repository's master branch.

When I click compare, it is shown that 0 files changed.

The reason why I have these commits:

- 8 commits were made to solve an issue, opened PR to the upstream repo, PR was successfully merged to the parent repo. While merging I chose the option to squash my 8 commits into 1 commit.

Then on my github forked repo page I had a message "your branch is 8 commits ahead, 3 commits behind"

- I have synced my local forked repo with the upstream repo.

```
$ git remote add upstream https://github.com/[Original Owner Username]/[Original Repository].git
$ git fetch upstream
$ git checkout master
$ git merge upstream/master
$ git push
```

While merging there were no conflicts. And due to merging local/master with upstream/master 1 more commit was created.

I guessed that updating the local forked repo and pushing changes to the github repo would help to resolve the issue. But, apparently, no.

Why do I still have 8 commits ahead, if they were already merged into the parent repo? Is it because of squashing while merging PR?

How can I get rid of these meaningless commits being ahead?